# How to copy Network layout created by estimateNetwork

Tags: r

I created two networks in R by function estimateNetwork, and then a I plotted them.
I need to comparate them by visual inspection, but the positions of nodes are different.
I should get the same (or similar) positions.

A reviewer told me: "You can do this by saving the layout of one of the graphs and use it as a base for layouts of other graphs in R".
I studied but I wasn't able to do that.

I found a solution in the library "igraph", but I'd like to keep my original layout without change my work.

This is the code I used:

```
#Network 1
net_f <- estimateNetwork(f, default="EBICglasso", tuning=0.5, corMethod = "npn", 
                         missing="listwise", sampleSize="maximum")

#Network 2
net_m <- estimateNetwork(m, default="EBICglasso", tuning=0.5, corMethod = "npn", 
                         missing="listwise", sampleSize="maximum")

#Plot Network 1
netq_f<-plot(net_f, layout="spring", groups=groups)

#Plot Network 2
netq_m<-plot(net_m, layout="spring", groups=groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
library("smacof")
mds_f<-mds(sim2diss(net_f$graph), type="mspline")
mds_m<-mds(sim2diss(net_m$graph), type="mspline")
fit_procrustes<-Procrustes(mds_f$conf, mds_m$conf)

#Plot Network 1
netq_f<-qgraph(net_f$graph, layout=fit_procrustes$X, groups=groups)

#Plot Network 2
netq_m<-qgraph(net_m$graph, layout=fit_procrustes$Yhat, groups=groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do this:

```
#Network 1
net_f <- estimateNetwork(f, default="EBICglasso", tuning=0.5, corMethod = "npn", 
                         missing="listwise", sampleSize="maximum")

#Network 2
net_m <- estimateNetwork(m, default="EBICglasso", tuning=0.5, corMethod = "npn", 
                         missing="listwise", sampleSize="maximum")

# Average layout:
library("qgraph")
L <- averageLayout(net_f$graph, net_m$graph)

#Plot Network 1
netq_f<-plot(net_f, layout=L, groups=groups)

#Plot Network 2
netq_m<-plot(net_m, layout=L, groups=groups)
```